# traverse through folder and do something with specific file types

Tags: bash

I'm working on a bash script that should go through a directory and print all files and if it hits a folder it should call it's self and do it again. I believe my problem lies with `if [[ $file =~ \.yml?yaml$ ]];` when I remove the tilda it runs but not correctly `if [[ $file = \.yml?yaml$ ]];`
It returns `"this a file isn't need -> $file"` even though it's a yaml.

```
#!/bin/bash

print_files_and_dirs() {
for file in $1/*;
   do
        if [ -f "$file"  ];
        then
                if [[ $file =~ \.yml?yaml$ ]];
                then
                        echo "this is a yaml file! -> $file"
                else
                        echo "this a file isn't need -> $file"
                fi
        else
                print_files_and_dirs $file
        fi
   done
}


print_files_and_dirs .
```

Comment: Do you really want to implement it with recursion?

Comment: If you are looking for files ending in `.yml` or `.yaml`, it's `\.(yml|yaml)$`, or `\.ya?ml` for short. `?` only applies to the immediately preceding regular expression, which is just the letter `l`.

Comment: You can also just write `[[ $file = *.@(yml|yaml) ]]`.

Comment: I get a syntax error when I apply the parenthesis `Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `find` to find the yaml files and do something with them.

```sh
find "$PWD" \
  -type f \( -name "*.yaml" -or -name "*.yml" \) \
  -exec echo found {} \;
```

If you only want the file name without the path, you could use printf to get the names and pipe it to `xargs`.

```sh
find "$PWD" \
  -type f \( -name "*.yaml" -or -name "*.yml" \) \
  -printf '%f\n' \
  | xargs -I{} echo found {}
```

Comment: How do I access the file name in the -exec for each found file?

Comment: @Mint, you access the file with the placeholder {}.